# open pdf view on click of link of a html page in laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf, dynamic, hyperlink

PDF generated but it just downloaded, not opened in a tab.
I want to open a random generated pdf page in a browser from where the user can download it.

I have tried pdf generating code? This is my controller.
Please suggest some code here in show function.

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Item;
use DB;
use Excel;
use PDF;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
//use App\Mail\DemoEmail;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;

class MaatwebsiteDemoController extends Controller
{

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function importExport()
    {
        return view('importExport');
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function downloadExcel($type)
    {
        $data = Item::get()->toArray();

        return Excel::create('itsolutionstuff_example', function ($excel) use ($data) {
            $excel->sheet('mySheet', function ($sheet) use ($data) {
                $sheet->fromArray($data);
            });
        })->download($type);
    }

    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function importExcel(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'import_file' => 'required'
        ]);

        $path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
        $data = Excel::load($path)->get();
        //echo "<pre>";
        //print_r($data);exit;

        if ($data->count()) {
            foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                foreach ($value as $key1 => $x1) {
                    $arr[] = ['email' => $x1->email, 'description' => $x1->description, 'content' => $x1->content];
                }
            }
            if (!empty($arr)) {
                Item::insert($arr);
            }
            //$data1 = Item::get()->toArray();
            $users = Item::get()->toArray();

            foreach ($users as $keycc => $user) {
                $data2[] = $user['email'];
                Mail::send('mails.demo', $user, function ($message) use ($user) {
                    $message->to($user['email'], 'Tutorials Point')->subject('Laravel HTML Testing Mail');
                    $message->from('smitamishra1992718@gmail.com', 'Smita');
                });
            }


            // Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($data){
            // return back()->with('success', 'Insert Record successfully.');

        }
    }
    //Here i am loading view as pdf bt it not open in a new tab as pdf it just dowloaded.
    public function show($id)
    {
        $users = DB::select('select * from items where id = ?', [$id]);
        //view()->share('users',$users);

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview', array('users' => $users));

        return $pdf->download('demo.pdf');
    }

    public function downloadPDF()

    {
        $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview');
        return $pdf->download('invoice.pdf');
    }
}
```

This is my view having a link.when we click on this link page open as pdf in browser.

```html
<a href="{{ route('pdfview', $id) }}">Content Detail Displayed here</a>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the readme of [barryvdh/laravel-dompdf](https://github.com/barryvdh/laravel-dompdf#using)

## Using

You can create a new DOMPDF instance and load a HTML string, file or view name. You can save it to a file, or stream (show in browser) or download.

```php
$pdf = App::make('dompdf.wrapper');
$pdf->loadHTML('<h1>Test</h1>');
return $pdf->stream();
```

The download function naturally downloads the file, use `stream()` instead

```php
public function show($id)
{
  $users = DB::select('select * from items where id = ?', [$id]);
  $pdf = PDF::loadView('pdfview', array('users' => $users));
  return $pdf->stream();
}
```

I hope this helps

Comment: Thanku so much for help.It's working now.I am new in laravel thanks for helping.

Comment: One more queries when we send mail using $users['email'] mail sent only to first two email address not on all email present in database.Could you please help.thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From your description, I think it's your browser setting that is preventing you from the preview of the pdf if it automatically downloads. If you are using Chromethen follow the instruction here to enable it. [Open PDFs in Chrome](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/6213030?hl=en) There is this part of the setting in the link above you should check if yours is set.
[image: Chrome pdf view setting]